# Preg_replace URLs and images in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have some string with text and I want to replace all image links to img tags and other links to a tags.

I already did that:

```
$row['message'] = preg_replace('/(http:\\/\\/.+(png|jpeg|jpg|gif|bmp))/Ui', '<img height="'.self::getConfig('image_height').'" src="$1" />', $row['message'], -1, $countImages);
```

How to replace all links except in img tags to a tag in `$row['message']`?

Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

Add a negative lookbehind to your regex to see if the URL follows `src="`.

```
$row['message'] = preg_replace('/(?<!src=")(http:\\/\\/.+(png|jpeg|jpg|gif|bmp))/Ui', '<img height="'.self::getConfig('image_height').'" src="$1" />', $row['message'], -1, $countImages);
```